# SQL related tricky count() query

Tags: sql, count

I have 4 tables :

`country`:

- id
- name

`region`:

- id
- name
- fk_country

`dept`:

- id
- name
- fk_region

`user`:

- id
- fk_country
- fk_region
- fk_dept

The `user` table has only one foreign key set (the others should be null).

We do not have to set the foreign key `fk_pays` because we can touch the `country` table via `fk_dept.fk_region.fk_country` (when `fk_dept` is set)

OR

via `fk_region.fk_country` (when `fk_region` is set)

This behavior was made to avoid redundancy.

My question is :

**How to fetch all country informations with an added column that contains the number of users (`COUNT`) in that country ?**

I know how to do using a different request for each pays (using `COALESCE`) but i wish to do that in a single.

Comment: I didn't try anything, it seems complex (join with an addition of different `COUNT` query)

Comment: `select country.*,count(user.id) from country,user where country.id = user.fk_country group by country.id`

Comment: I'm not trying to do a simple `COUNT` query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use OR in join

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, count(DISTINCT u.id)
FROM country AS c
JOIN region AS r ON c.id=r.fk_country
JOIN dept AS d ON r.id=d.fk_region
JOIN users AS u ON u.fk_country=c.id OR u.fk_region=r.id OR u.fk_dept=d.id
GROUP BY c.id,c.name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3026f/1

Comment: Not so complex finally, smart :)

Comment: @Leto actualy it wasn't working correctly. Now it should be okay.

Comment: Why does an user be more than one time fetched ?

Comment: @Leto Because when user is connected to the country he gets joined with every row that has that country, that is to every region and district in that country.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT count(user.id), country.name, region.name, dept.name FROM user
   JOIN country ON user.fk_country = country.id
   JOIN region ON region.fk_country = country.id
   JOIN dept ON dept.fk_region = region.id
       GROUP BY country.id
```

Comment: This suppose that `user.fk_country` is set, but it is not always. Further, what's the purpose of the two next joins ? (except selecting columns ?)

Comment: What user count are you expecting if user is not related to any country. It does an INNER JOIN, which means that it counts users in the countries provided. JOIN's are done for selecting "FULL" information, as in the answer you've marked. I haven't noticed that you have all the fk's in the user table